# In Matlab, how do I generate 10 random seeds?

Tags: matlab

I have the code below that I was told I need to use different seeds to generate my random numbers 10 times and then average those in order to get a smoother graph.  I don't have much experience in using Matlab so I don't know much about how these seeds work even after reading the documentation.

```
% Create an array
S = 0:20;
CW = 0:5:100;
S(1) = 0;
CW(1) = 0;

counter = 2;  % Counter for the nuber of S 
N = 20;  % Number of nodes

% Collect data for each increment of 5 up to 100 for CW values
for i = 5:5:100

    T = 10000 / i;  % Total number of cycles

    % Create array of next transmission times for N nodes
    transmission_time = floor(i * rng(1, N)); 
    total_success = 0;

    % Loop for T cycles
    for t = 1:T

        % For 0 to the number of contention windows
        for pos = 0:i-1

           % Count the number of nodes that have the current CW
            count = 0;
            for node = 1:N
               if transmission_time(node) == pos
                   count = count + 1;
               end
            end

            % If there is more than 1, then a collision occurs
            collision = false;
            if count > 1
                collision = true;
            % If there is exactly 1, then there is a success
            elseif count == 1
                total_success = total_success + 1;
            end 

            % If there is a collision, reassign new transmissions times
            if collision == true
                for node = 1:N
                    if node == pos
                        transmission_time(node) = floor(i * rand(1));
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    % Display the ratio of successes
    S(counter) = total_success / (T * i);
    counter = counter + 1;
end

% Plot the graph for Success vs CW
plot(CW, S, 'o-');
xlabel('Contention Window, CW');
ylabel('Throughput, S');
```

Comment: You don't generally need several seeds. Use just one, and generate all random numbers you want

Comment: One seed is all you need.  If you think you need more, you don't understand how random numbers work.  Perhaps you mean multiple samples from a given probability function.

Comment: Take a look at `rng`, but this method sound really strange. No idea why taking 10 numbers from 10 different seeds should help. Seems someone is assuming one of those bad random number generators, which matlab definitely isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for all the confusion.  I think some of you were right by saying I didn't need to generate different streams.

In the code above there is a line that says "if node == pos", this is incorrect and should be "if transmission_time(node) == pos".

That one line was what was causing my graph to be all out of whack.  I also needed to generate new random numbers for successful data packets as well.

Thanks for all your suggestions though!  I know a lot more about how randomness works with seeds in Matlab now though!

Answer (score 1):

From the matlab [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/generate-random-numbers-that-are-different.html)

> Frequent reseeding of the generator does not improve the statistical
>   properties of the output and does not make the output more random in
>   any real sense. Reseeding can be useful when you restart MATLAB or
>   before you run a large calculation involving random numbers. However,
>   reseeding the generator too frequently within a session is not a good
>   idea because the statistical properties of your random numbers can be
>   adversely affected.

---

You don't need to use different seeds with `rand`: it will not generate the same number sequences every time you run it. For instance

```
R = zeros(1e5,1);
for ii = 1:1e5
    R(ii) = rand;
end
Rsorted = sort(R);
dRsorted = diff(Rsorted);
find(dRsorted == 0)
```

will return and empty matrix: `rand` never returns an identical random number in 100,000 successive calls.

Also, in your code, there is something wrong. The line `transmission_time = floor(i * rng(1, N));` should read `transmission_time = floor(i * rand(1, N));`.

If you want to use a different seed for each cycle, you may add the following call before using rand for the first time: `rng(i);`. With it, you will be able to control the random number generated (`rand` will produce a predictable sequence of numbers).

Comment: The question is about using 10 random number streams from different seeds in parallel, without resetting each.

Comment: My professor stated that I would need to use 10 different seeds because the default rand() generates the same number sequences every time you run it.

Comment: @KrisPurdy  It is very likely that your professor was referring to the implementation of `rand()` from another language besides Matlab.  C++ for example, will give you the same sequence of random numbers every time you run the program unless you give it a random seed.  The only time it makes sense to seed the RNG in Matlab is when you ***want to*** generate the same number sequence every time.

Comment: @nispio - ...or if you provide a seed based on the clock, as with the undocumented `RandStream.shuffleSeed` method.  By the way, MATLAB too will give you the same sequence of numbers because it has a default seed.  Open MATLAB, `rand`, close MATLAB, open MATLAB, `rand`.  Same number!  The difference is that MATLAB has a default generator that gets used globally and not reset unless MATLAB closes, or you `reset` it or set a new seed.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed true that if you have some kind of simulation, running it multiple times with the same random numbers is useless. There are basically two solutions for this:

**1. Very easy, does not generate reproducible results**

At the start of your code, set `rng` to something based on `now`.

This way you will have different results each time.

**2. Easy and recommended, generates reproducible results**

Wrap your simulations in a loop, if you do them sequentially each time you will have a differerent result from your simulation (thus allowing you to average out) and the results can still be reproduced.

---

Note that usually if you want to reduce the volatility from a simulation, you don't need to run it multiple times, but can just let it run longer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems more straightforward to have a single stream and simply generate 10 times as many data samples. However, you can create 10 random streams with different seeds if you want to pull from them in parallel, maybe with `parfor`, for example.  If you are still looking for a way to do this, there are two well documented methods of which I am aware:

1. Multiple streams for any stream type
2. [Substreams](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/11/05/new-ways-with-random-numbers-part-i/#15) for the `'mrg32k3a'` and `'mlfg6331_64'` types

### Multiple streams

Start with an example of a creating a cell array of 10 streams with different seeds:

```
s = 0:9;
r = arrayfun(@(t)RandStream('mcg16807','Seed',t),s,'uni',false); % RandStreams
```

Using the same seeds in `s` will give a deterministic simulation, which always gives the same results.  That is,

```
>> r = arrayfun(@(t)RandStream('mcg16807','Seed',t),s,'uni',false);
>> r{1}.rand
ans =
          0.21895918632809
>> r{2}.rand
ans =
         0.512908935785717
>> clear r
>> r = arrayfun(@(t)RandStream('mcg16807','Seed',t),s,'uni',false);
>> r{1}.rand
ans =
          0.21895918632809
>> r{2}.rand
ans =
         0.512908935785717
```

The `RandomStream` instances stored in the cell array `r` have the following familiar methods: `rand`, `randn`, `randi` and `randperm`. The `reset` method will start the same sequence of random numbers over.

If you do not want the simulation to be deterministic, but more random in a sense, you can create a different seed vector `s` based on the time via the *undocumented* `shuffleSeed` method:

```
s = zeros(1,10);
for i=1:numel(s), s(i)=RandStream.shuffleSeed; end
```

and regenerate the streams.

### Substreams

Substreams attempt to evenly distribute the seeds (or "checkpoints") in the random number stream. However, the real benefit of substreams is supposedly just ease of reproducibility. This does seem most straightforward since you just create one stream and switch to a different stream whenever desired.  For example,

```
>> stream = RandStream('mrg32k3a');
>> stream.get('Substream')
ans =
 1
>> samps1 = stream.rand(1,20);  % some samplesfrom substream 1
```

Then change the substream and get more samples:

```
>> stream.Substream = 2;
>> samps2 = stream.rand(1,20);  % some samplesfrom substream 2
```

However, note that this still doesn't improve randomness of the samples:

> you don't have to worry about "using up" all the values in each substream before moving to the next one, but it would be pointless to take the other extreme and jump to a different substream every time you generate a new value. Substreams don't add randomness, they just make it easier to reproduce values.

As such, I don't see the point of using more than one random number stream/seed for random number generation in your application.