# Different (pseudo) random numbers in parallel loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, parallel-processing, parfor

Asking for random numbers in a **parallel loop always return the same pseudo random numbers**. How can I avoid this?

```
% workers initialization:
if matlabpool('size') == 0
    matlabpool('open',2);
else
    matlabpool('close');
    matlabpool('open',2);
end

% parallel loop always give the same random numbers...
parfor k = 1:10
    fprintf([num2str(rand(1,1)), ' ']);
end
```

One ideal solution would be to initialize the pseudo random number generator in each thread by CPU time or similar. Things like `rng('shuffle')` don't seem to help here...

**console output:**

```
Sending a stop signal to all the workers ... stopped.
Starting matlabpool using the 'local' profile ... connected to 2 workers.
0.32457 0.66182 0.63488 0.64968 
0.26459 0.096779 0.50518 0.48662 0.034895 0.85227
```

Comment: But you have 10 different numbers there, where are the repeats? Or are you saying you always get those 10?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random Number Generator Matlab with Multiple CPUs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150432/random-number-generator-matlab-with-multiple-cpus)

Comment: @Dan: Yes, that's what I am saying :-) It is like the pseudo random number generators are always initialized with the same number in each of the threads (maybe based on the thread number?)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19670256/2778484) may be of help, particularly the part about the `RandStream.shuffleSeed` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Matlab, how do I generate 10 random seeds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664162/in-matlab-how-do-i-generate-10-random-seeds)

Comment: at thewaywewalk: it is absolutly not a duplicate of your suggestion. at horchler: you are right, the question is the same, nevertheless the answer given by Edric is different from the answers given there and interesting at the same time; all in all closing the question shouldn't be an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [documentation here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/control-random-number-streams.html) about various options here. Here's one way you might do something close.

```
numWorkers = matlabpool('size');
[streams{1:numWorkers}] = RandStream.create('mrg32k3a', ...
    'Seed', 'shuffle', 'NumStreams', numWorkers);
spmd
    RandStream.setGlobalStream(streams{labindex});
end
```

Or, to avoid creating all the streams at the client, you could do this instead:

```
rng('shuffle'); % shuffle the client
workerSeed = randi([0, 2^32-1]);
spmd
    stream = RandStream.create('mrg32k3a', ...
        'Seed', workerSeed, ...
        'NumStreams', numlabs, ...
        'StreamIndices', labindex);
    RandStream.setGlobalStream(stream);
end
```

Comment: Thank you, really helpful! To be honest, I do not really understand the difference between your approaches.

Comment: The main difference is that in the second case, I'm building individual RandStream objects on each worker, rather than building all the objects at the client and sending them over. This would be more significant if you had a large number of workers.